# Process any array without using For Loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to achieve Output **dynamically** without using **FOR** Loop.
Input is array of multiple objects.

```js
var input = [
  {
    "name": "Siner1",
    "RTime": 40,
    "FTime": 30
  },
  {
    "name": "Siner2",
    "RTime": 50,
    "FTime": 60
  }
]

var output = [
  {
    "RTime": {
      "Siner1": 40,
      "Siner2": 50
    },
    "FTime": {
      "Siner1": 30,
      "Siner2": 60
    }

  }
]

//console.log(input)
console.log(output);
```

Can someone assist me on this.

Comment: use array `map` method - actually, you'd need something like array reduce for this

Comment: can you use forEach?

Comment: Where are you stuck? If you need assistance, you should describe the part you're having trouble with.

Comment: ...since you're excluding `for` loops for some reason, does that imply that you have a current solution that uses a loop?

Comment: `const output = Object.entries(input.reduce((r,o)=>(r.RTime[o.name]=o.RTime,r.FTime[o.name]=o.FTime,r),{RTime:{},FTime:{}})).map(([k,v])=>({[k]:v}));`

Comment: are the keys of each object are also moving targets except of `name`?

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to use a for loop?

Comment: The desired output actually should be either a list of group items ... `[{ "RTime": { ... } }, { "FTime": { ... } }, ...]` or a group structured object ...`{ "RTime": { ... }, "FTime": { ... }, ... }` and not the latter being in addition the sole item of an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Approach 1

```js
var input = [
  {
    "name": "Siner1",
    "RTime": 40,
    "FTime": 30
  },
  {
    "name": "Siner2",
    "RTime": 50,
    "FTime": 60
  }
]

var output = input.reduce(function(initial,next){
   initial["RTime"][next["name"]]=(initial["RTime"][next["name"]] || 0 ) + next["RTime"];
   initial["FTime"][next["name"]]=(initial["FTime"][next["name"]] || 0 ) + next["FTime"];
   return initial;
},{"RTime":{},"FTime":{}});



console.log(output)
```

### Approach 2

In the event that there are other keys or values you would like to aggregate

```js
var input = [
  {
    "name": "Siner1",
    "RTime": 40,
    "FTime": 30
  },
  {
    "name": "Siner2",
    "RTime": 50,
    "FTime": 60
  }
]

var keys = ['RTime','FTime'];
output=input.reduce(function(initial,next){
   keys.map(function(key){
        initial[key][next["name"]]=(initial[key][next["name"]] || 0 ) + next[key];
   });
   return initial;
},keys.reduce(function(data,key){
   data[key]={};
   return data;
},{}));

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

The provided generic approach is based on [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). Since it uses the [`accumulator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Description) argument of its callback function as a configurable `collector` it is totally agnostic about the keys of any processed item of any given list. One just needs to provide the (source) key of a processed item that's value then serves as target key of newly grouped key values ...

```js
function restructureKeysAndValues(collector, item) {
  const {
    keyOfTargetValue,
    registry,
    index,
    list
  } = collector;
  const targetKey = item[keyOfTargetValue];

  Object.entries(item).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (key !== keyOfTargetValue) {

      let keyGroup = registry[key];
      if (!keyGroup) {
        keyGroup = registry[key] = { [key]: {} };

        Object.assign(index, keyGroup);
        list.push(keyGroup);
      }
      keyGroup[key][targetKey] = value;
    }
  });
  return collector;
}

console.log('a list of group objects ...', [{

    "name": "Siner1",
    "RTime": 40,
    "FTime": 30
  }, {
    "name": "Siner2",
    "RTime": 50,
    "FTime": 60

  }].reduce(restructureKeysAndValues, {

    keyOfTargetValue: 'name',
    registry: {}, // - for internal tracking
    index: {},    // - for external use, output as map/index. 
    list: []      // - for external use, output as array/list.

  }).list
);

console.log('a single grouped object ...', [{

    "name": "Siner1",
    "RTime": 40,
    "FTime": 30
  }, {
    "name": "Siner2",
    "RTime": 50,
    "FTime": 60

  }].reduce(restructureKeysAndValues, {

    keyOfTargetValue: 'name',
    registry: {}, // - for internal tracking
    index: {},    // - for external use, output as map/index. 
    list: []      // - for external use, output as array/list.

  }).index
);

console.log('a list of group objects ...', [{

    "name": "Siner1",
    "RTime": 40,
    "FTime": 30,
    "CTime": 70,
    "ATime": 90
  }, {
    "name": "Siner2",
    "RTime": 50,
    "FTime": 60,
    "CTime": 30,
    "ATime": 40
  }, {
    "name": "Siner3",
    "RTime": 90,
    "FTime": 20,
    "CTime": 10,
    "ATime": 20

  }].reduce(restructureKeysAndValues, {

    keyOfTargetValue: 'name',
    registry: {}, // - for internal tracking
    index: {},    // - for external use, output as map/index. 
    list: []      // - for external use, output as array/list.

  }).list
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```